# How can I resolve this casting error?

Tags: vb.net

With the help of @competent_tech I have been able to get my comboboxitems to be selected via a button click and parsed through some VB code to get a document displayed.

Everything seemed to be working fine, until I decided to bind the combobox to an XML file using the following code:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vehicleID}, XPath=//manualtype/ipck/vin}" IsReadOnly="True"></ComboBox>
```

This is the code I'm using on the button.click event:

```
Try
        Dim sFileName As String

        If ComboBox1.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
            sFileName = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString()
            Dim theDocument As New System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\EMR", sFileName & "ipck.xps"), System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
            DocumentViewer1.Document = theDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

The combobox is working fine - displaying the values from the XML file, however, I am now getting an error message whenever I select an item and click the button.  The error message states:  "UNABLE TO CAST OBJECT OF TYPE 'SYSTEM.STRING' TO TYPE 'SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CONTROLS.COMBOBOXITEM'.

Please help me resolve this problem, as I'd like to be able to update the comboboxitem list via the XML file rather than having to recode the software each time I want to update the list.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it not true that the SelectedValue is a string already? And that the SelectedItem is a ComboBoxItem?

Comment: Not to try and sound condescending, but taking some time to learn how to use a debugger will really pay off in the long run. Simply setting breakpoints and using the watch window will help you immensely. So many programmers I run into are abysmal at debugging and it's one of most important skills you can develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to cast ComboBox1.SelectedValue which is a string to a ComboBoxItem object.

I think you could just use:

```
sFileName = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
```

Or is your combobox not a list of file names?

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.  Wow, somebody I'll finally get this coding stuff.  So basically, in what situation would the DirectCast method be called?

Comment: You want to use casting when you need to change types.  So say you have a string "1" and an int 4 and you want to add them.  You would need to cast the string "1" to an int 1 so you can add it to 4.  Thats doesn't really apply in your case here.